# Google Apps Scripts ReferenceError: "setTimeout" is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is there a way for me to delay a function call in Google Apps Scripts? I'm currently testing for smaller time frames, but I would eventually like to have a 72-hour wait period between processing data and calling moveRows.

I was trying to achieve this by making this Javascript function call:

```
setTimeout(function() { moveRows(arrayOfRows); }, 3000);
```

I also tried doing it with a trigger but my function never got called.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('moveRows(arrayofRows)')
.timeBased()
.everyMinutes(1)
.create()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: setTimeout is not part of JavaScript, is part of client-side browser programming. use triggers. you cant pass parameters to triggers, use other means like script properties.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, `setTimeout` cannot be used in GAS. Instead, you can use the function `[Utilities.sleep()][1]` (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29659405/9593181)).

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout() belongs to the 'window' object that is not present in GAS. Remember, the code is compiled on Google servers, not in your browser, so you don't have access to DOM in this environment. Similarly, you can't reference 'document' or other DOM objects. The only place where it's possible is client-side HTML that HtmlService creates and sends to your browser for rendering.

You can only pass function name as parameter to the newTrigger() method. You are passing the parameter, which is why it doesn't work.